# Is there any way to number the scenarios and it's steps?

Tags: cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

As we write feature file which contains several scenarios, which contains several closely worded, closely meaning step definitions, I am thinking of numbering them. Like if a step 3 of a scenario 2 would be named as s23. I tried doing it like...

```
Scenario: This is my scenario
  Given S21the user has some thing
  When S22the user does some thing
  Then S23we can make sure some thing is anything.
```

This is supposedly help me identify the corresponding stepdefinition implementation methods quickly, and console log message linked to the step definitions etc.

But this resulted in the numbering S21,S22, S23 etc., getting treated as integer arguments in the auto generated step definitions. How can avoid that ?

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber is a communication tool, not a test scripting language. Would your business users be able to understand this notation? Would it help them make sense of the scenarios? This kind of approach defeats the purpose of Cucumber as a living documentation and communication tool, and should be avoided. If your step definitions are ambiguous, add some more context (in business readable language) to make them less so.

Your IDE should help you step between Gherkin scenarios and the source code; you shouldn't need to have to add extra information in the scenarios for this.

You also don't need to use the auto generated step definitions - they are just there as a convenience and you can write your own.

Comment: Thanks John for your kind reply !

Comment: Thanks John for your kind reply !
I agree to all your points, especially about IDE would help navigate between gherkin scenarios and the source code, which I am doing right now (only after converting the project as a Cucumber project, then the Cucumber Eclipse plugin make it possible)

My ask is during the development when a web locator is giving trouble, it is becoming increasingly difficult to wade through the console log for the right place where the problem is reported.
Especially Serenity gives an extensive amount of log. If I could number the step definitions, I could search console

Comment: BTW, in my Client place, the business users are just spectators. They explain the business need, how do they navigate the website(financial one), I go about writing the feature file and code it and demo them. They don't care or understand what goes on in the feature file as long as they are able to see the excellent reporting produced by the Serenity framework.